# Eclipse shortcut to extract string value to local variable

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

```
String test = var1 + "something";
```

what is the shortcut to extract "something" into variable? Searched in SO but found no question related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Select the String including the double quotes and hit `Alt + Shift + L`

See Extract Local Variable at [List of eclipse key bindings](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-keybindings.htm) for reference

Answer (score 1):

```
Ctr+L,2
```

Assume you have done the following `"".length()` and want  to store the result in an integer
go anywhere on the instruction `"".length()` and press `Ctrl+L`  a small window on the right bottom of the screen will open. Press `L` after that.

Please note it is not case sensitive.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Ctrl+2, L

Answer (score 0):

select the value with double quotes and then press `ctrl+1`

or go to

`Refactor -> Extract local variable`